# Global variable and import

Tags: python

Let's consider a file called `test1.py` and containing the following code:

```
def init_foo():
    global foo 
    foo=10
```

Let's consider another file called `test2.py` and containing the following:

```
import test1

test1.init_foo()
print(foo)
```

Provided that `test1` is on the pythonpath (and gets imported correctly) I will now receive the following error message:

`NameError: name 'foo' is not defined`

Anyone can explain to me why the variable `foo` is not declared as a `global` in the scope of `test2.py` while it is run? Also if you can provide a workaround for that problem?

Thx!

Comment: "Global" means "module-scoped", and specifically, scoped to the module where the code is defined. There exists no such thing in Python as a scope that spans multiple modules, or a means to refer to the calling module's variables (which is for the better -- if the language *did* support a thing, you'd never be able to use a 3rd-party module without first checking if its global names conflicted with yours).

Comment: "Also if you can provide a workaround for that problem?" Don't design your program to depend on shared global state across modules... Even global state within modules is iffy..

Answer (score 0):

why use global though? Just return it

test1.py

```
def init_foo():
    foo = 10
    return foo
```

test2.py

```
foo = test1.init_foo()
print(foo)
```

Comment: Ok thx for your answer, which is the workaround. But why is the global not working?

Comment: @jimbasquiat `foo` is a global variable just at the file-level in the file `test1.py`. So, you need to do `test1.foo` to access it in a different file `test2.py`.

Answer (score 0):

In `test2.py`, do `print(test1.foo)` instead of `print(foo)` and it will work.